# Is vector addition continuous under arbitrary norms

Tags: vector-spaces, continuity

Suppose $X$ is a normed space, and $X\times X$ is the vector space with vector addition and such defined component-wise, equipped with some norm. Then is $(x, y) \mapsto x + y$ continuous?

I know that if the norm is just $(x, y) \mapsto |x| + |y|$ then this is satisfied, but what if theres some other norm?

Answer (score 2):

No, not if you pick an *unrelated* norm on the product.

Assume we already have two not topologically equivalent norms $|\cdot|_1$ and $|\cdot|_2$ on $X$. Then addition may not be continuous if we take the norm induced by $|\cdot|_1$ on $X\times X$ and $|\cdot|_2$ on $X$.

Comment: In particular, if the topology induced by $|\cdot |_1$ on $X$ does not contain the topology induced by $|\cdot|_2$, addition will not be continuous, since if you restrict to $X\times\{0\}$ addition is just the projection.

Comment: you are saying $(x,y) \mapsto \phi(x+y)$ can be not continuous where $\phi$ is a linear mapping between different normed vector spaces, which is obvious, and that sometimes $\phi$ is implicit,  when it is the canonical embedding of $(X,|.|_1)$ into $(X,|.|_2)$ (for example $\phi : l^1 \to l^2$)

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{R}$ then any two norms on $X$ determine the same topology and vector addition will be continuous with respect to that that topology.

If $X$ is infinite-dimensional then different norms on $X$ can give different topologies on $X$ and you can't expect vector addition to be continuous if you choose an arbitrary norm on $X \times X$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true in general, suppose it was true, consider two norms $\| \|_i, i=1,2$ defined on $X$,
 and endow $X\times X$ with $\|\|_2\times \|\|_2$. Set $f:X\times X\rightarrow (X,\|\|_1): f(x,y)=x+y$, consider $i:(X,\|\|_2)\rightarrow X\times X$ defined by $i(x)=(x,0)$, $i$ is continue and $f\circ i=Id_X:(X,\|\|_2)\rightarrow (X,\|\|_1)$ is continue. A similar argument implies that $Id_X:(X,\|\|_1)\rightarrow (X,\|\|_2)$ is continue. This is equivalent to saying that $\|\|_1$ and $\|\|_2$ are equivalent, 
(see the answer here [Equivalent norms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109733/equivalent-norms) )a fact which is not always true.

Comment: Why ? I believe such an argument exists, just replace $\|\|_1$ by $\|\|_2$ and $\|\|_2$ by $\|\|_1$.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're assuming that the statement is true in general, not just in the one example you start with.